# Android Facebook login Which information to store

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have tried to look for information by using different search strings but still could not locate the information i want or may be i m not using proper search string.
I have integrated facebook login into my android application. 
**My question is what information should i store in my database so when session is expired and user logs in again, they do not have to register again with my app rather using the information i get in login i can query my database and get the user information.**

Functionality in the application is

1. User login using facebook
2. Query database to get profile details. (Here which information to store from facebook login so can identify the user uniquely).
3. If profile not found display create profile screen.
4. If profile already created and fetched from database then display dashboard.

I have already implemented facebook login and i m able to fetch name and email.

My app do not require posting of any kind of data on user wall or anything just require for login purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only data you need to store to identify returning users is the App Scoped ID. Emails can change, but the App Scoped ID will stay the same for the same user.

Comment: this will remain same even if user delete facebook app and connect again?